# Развертывание сервера Red5 на Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: red5, ubuntu

Нужно развернуть сервер, если есть у кого-нибудь подробная руководство, дайте ссылку плииииззз.

Answer (score 2):

А чем официальное "[руководство по Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html)" не подходит? Или [то, что наши переводят](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server)?